# React CLI web directory

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

I created a react app using the react CLI. In dev it runs from the root of the web server:

> http://localhost:3000

using npm start:

> "start": "react-scripts start"

When I run the build to deploy it, I need to put it into a specific web site on our IIS server, so the url will end up being:

> https://web-server/**MyApp**

I know I have to change my react routing but I don't know how to tell the react start script to always work from a web directory in a specific folder, and to include that in the build. Is this possible? I want to run the app in dev mode from the folder I will be deploying it to so I don't have to constantly change it. I also don't want to have to modify the react scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it. In the package.json, I specified a homepage:

```
"homepage": "https://myserver/MyApp",
```

Then I updated the routing:

```
<Route path="/MyApp" components={App}>
```

When I deployed it to IIS it work perfect. The details can be found on the react CLI github site:

[Building for Relative Paths](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths)